# Require answers to multiple radio buttons to go to next page HTML

Tags: javascript, html, survey

I am setting up a multipage survey/study that has 2 multiple choice radio button questions per page (with the exception of the first page, which requires no answer). I have a next function that checks to make sure an answer has been given. It works, but when passed two values so that it will check two questions, it only checks one of them. I used console.log to display the name passing through the function, and only one name gets passed. I can go to the next page by answering only one of the questions, even if it's not the one passing through the function according to the name in the console log. How can I get it to check all of the questions that I specify in onclick?

Here is the code for the Continue button with the next() function for onclick. When I pass both names, it will only check 1 of the 2.

```
<input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="next('Q1Answer','Q1Rating');"/>
```

These are the radio buttons:

Question 1

```
<input name="Q1Answer" type="radio" value="Right" /> Right&emsp;
<input name="Q1Answer" type="radio" value="Wrong" /> Wrong
```

Question 2

```
Less confident &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <input class="rating" name="Qrating" type="radio" id="v1" value="1" />
    <input class="rating" name="Qrating" type="radio" id="v2" value="2" />
    <input class="rating" name="Qrating" type="radio" id="v3" value="3" />
    <input class="rating" name="Qrating" type="radio" id="v4" value="4" />
    <input class="rating" name="Qrating" type="radio" id="v5" value="5" />
&nbsp; &nbsp; More confident
```

This is the current version of my next function. I added a for loop to try to get it to iterate through all of the items passed to it, but that isn't solving the issue (it worked the same way without the loop). This code is in a javascript file that I call in the HTML code.

```
function next(name) {
    for (i in name) {
        if (name.startsWith('Q')) {
            if (!document.querySelectorAll('input[name]:checked').length) {
                alert("Please answer the question.");
                return;
}
}
}   
    current++;
    swap(effectivePage(current - 1), effectivePage(current));
}
```

(swap and effectivePage are other functions for progressing to the next page, I can add those if needed to test)

I've used name as the identifier, but could easily replace with ID if that would somehow make this easier. I used the startsWith if condition so that only actual questions would get checked.

I have basic HTML knowledge and don't know Javascript at all beyond what I've taught myself to try to figure this out, so I'm hoping the solution is a simple one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find 2 problems which were keeping your code from performing the way you wanted. When you created your next call in the HTML, you tried to pass in multiple name strings, but your `next` function only takes in one parameter. This means that your calls were only ever getting the first string to check against which in this case was Q1Answer. If you change the value being passed in to an array of strings, then you can perform the checking against all the names you need. Also, be sure to pass the **exact name** of the inputs you want to check against in that next call. If those names are incorrect your code will make it so the user can never reach the next page as it will think that that input was never selected (because it won't find that input at all on the page).

Second, when you were performing the checking by using the query selector, you weren't checking against any specific names so it was always finding the selected first value even if it should have been checking for the second input tag. I have modified that check to now specifically look for the name passed in so it will only match against the input in question (ie, the first pass will check for Q1Answer and the second pass will check for Qrating).

```js
function next(name) {
  for (i in name) {
    if (name[i].startsWith('Q')) {
      if (!document.querySelectorAll('input[name=' + name[i] + ']:checked').length) {
        alert("Please answer the question.");
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  current++;
  swap(effectivePage(current - 1), effectivePage(current));
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="next(['Q1Answer','Qrating']);" />

<input name="Q1Answer" type="radio" value="Right" /> Right&emsp;
<input name="Q1Answer" type="radio" value="Wrong" /> Wrong

<br/> Less confident &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input class="rating" name="Qrating" type="radio" id="v1" value="1" />
<input class="rating" name="Qrating" type="radio" id="v2" value="2" />
<input class="rating" name="Qrating" type="radio" id="v3" value="3" />
<input class="rating" name="Qrating" type="radio" id="v4" value="4" />
<input class="rating" name="Qrating" type="radio" id="v5" value="5" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; More confident
```

Comment: Thanks! I did realize eventually that part of my problem was that the function only took one parameter (I don't know JS but I know other languages, so I should have picked up on that sooner!). The key seems to using the brackets to pass in an array of values to check. Once you do that I've found a few different ways (including your solution) to accomplish the checking in the JS function, but you have to get the right elements in there first.